# How to delete the autofill data stored by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, textfield, autofill

**How to delete the autofill data stored by Chrome which keeps popping up every time I bring my cursor to a blank field?**

Comment: [explained](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3145489/browsers/how-to-clear-unwanted-autofill-entries-in-google-chrome.html)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My facebook login page and search boxes on several websites still keep displaying everything I have entered in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily in Google Chrome using **Shift+Delete**. Now if you wish to delete the entire autofill history for a certain period, clear the browser history for the period

For selective deletion,

1. **Click on the field with the undesired autofill.**
2. **In the dropdown menu that appears, bring the selection to the autofill entry you wish to delete**
3. **Press Shift+Delete**

Also remember that it's always convenient to browse in cognito when you don't want your data to get automatically stored.